# How to convert mp4 to mp3 in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have the mp4 link of a video but don't have a link for the mp3 version of that mp4 video. So is there any way that I can convert that mp4 video to mp3 in Android? I saw some resources but nothing works for me. I have two ways in which I believe this can be achieved

1. Convert the mp4 link to mp3 directly. (Not Sure if this is achievable)
2. Download the mp4 on the device with the help of a link and then use some code to convert that mp4 to mp3.

I also tried some solutions which are available online

https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

I tried the above library to achieve the final goal. But got: `Async command execution failed with returnCode=1`.

This error in the code I am using is:

```
private class Mp4ToMp3ConverterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String mp4FilePath = params[0];
        String mp3OutputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/output.mp3";

        String[] ffmpegCommand = {"-i", mp4FilePath, "-vn", "-ar", "44100", "-ac", "2", "-b:a", "192k", mp3OutputPath};


        Config.enableStatisticsCallback(new StatisticsCallback() {
            public void apply(Statistics newStatistics) {
                Log.d("Dekh", String.format("frame: %d, time: %d", newStatistics.getVideoFrameNumber(), newStatistics.getTime()));
            }
        });

        long executionIdd = FFmpeg.executeAsync(ffmpegCommand, new ExecuteCallback() {
            @Override
            public void apply(final long executionId, final int returnCode) {
                if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
                    Log.i("Dekh", "Async command execution completed successfully.");
                } else if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
                    Log.i("Dekh", "Async command execution cancelled by user.");
                } else {
                    Log.i("Dekh", String.format("Async command execution failed with returnCode=%d.", returnCode));
                }
            }
        });

        FFmpeg.cancel(executionIdd);

        return mp3OutputPath;
    }
}
```

Solution number 2 which I used is:

https://androidprogrammatically425516919.wordpress.com/2020/04/21/how-to-convert-video-to-audio-in-android-programmatically/

But I got an error here also: `Failed to instantiate extractor`.
And another error is: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`

I tried the online available solution to solve these errors but nothing worked. Such as granting write permission. Providing a valid location to save the output.

But nothing works so far. Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Youd should post the entire log of your async task execution. With return code you cannot tell much, just looking their github docs it seems there's no exact meaning for error codes.

Comment: Thanks for your response This is the only error I'm getting. But I solved my problem in another way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: btw, possible duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650778/flutter-ffmpeg-exit-code-1